# How to find all anchor tags inside a div using Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So this is how my HTML looks that I'm parsing. It is all within a table and gets repeated multiple times and I just want the `href` attribute value that is inside the div with the attribute `class="Special_Div_Name"`.  All these divs are then inside table rows and there are lots of rows.

```
<tr>
   <div class="Special_Div_Name">
      <a href="something.mp3">text</a>
   </div>
</tr>
```

What I want is only the `href` attribute values that end in ".mp3" that are inside the div with the attribute `class="Special_Div_Name"`.

So far I was able to come up with this code:

```
download = soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.mp3'))
for text in download:
    hrefText = (text['href'])
    print hrefText
```

This code currently prints off every `href` attribute value on the page that ends in ".mp3" and it's very close to doing exactly what I want.  Its just I only want the ".mp3"s that are inside that div class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This minor adjustment should get you what you want:

```
special_divs = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Special_Div_Name'})
for text in special_divs:
    download = text.find_all('a', href = re.compile('\.mp3$'))
    for text in download:
        hrefText = (text['href'])
        print hrefText
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and logically it makes sense so I kind of understand how this works!  Only problem is I had a hard time figuring out how to implement it in my code because you used just "d" as a variable and I missed this with d.find_all() so maybe name that something better so future people don't miss it as well.

Comment: Good call! I'll switch it back. Happy to help :)

Comment: `re.compile('.mp3')` would match `<a href="textmp3">text</a>`; you want `re.compile('\.mp3$')` as stated in my answer since `.` has special meaning in a regular expression; the anchor `$` denotes that it should match the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that something was wrong there but OP said that was working for his example :)

Comment: @JoshCrozier  yes that is a better re to use in this case!  I'll switch my code to use this as well thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since Beautiful Soup accepts most [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with the [`.select()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), I'd suggest using the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[href$=".mp3"]` in order to select `a` elements with an `href` attribute ending with `.mp3`.

Then you can just prepend the selector `.Special_Div_Name` in order to only select anchor elements that are descendants:

```
for a in soup.select('div.Special_Div_Name a[href$=".mp3"]'):
    print (a['href'])
```

In a more general case, if you would just like to select `a` elements with an `[href]` attribute that are a descendant of a `div` element, then you would use the selector `div a[href]`:

```
for a in soup.select('div a[href]'):
    print (a)
```

---

If you don't use the code above, then based on the original code that you provided, you would need to select all the elements with a class of `Special_Div_Name`, then you would need to iterate over those elements and select the descendant anchor elements:

```
for div in soup.select('.Special_Div_Name'):
    for a in div.find_all('a', href = re.compile('\.mp3$')):
        print (a['href'])
```

As a side note, `re.compile('.mp3')` should be `re.compile('\.mp3$')` since `.` has special meaning in a regular expression. In addition, you will also want the anchor `$` in order to match at the end of the sting (rather than anywhere in the string).

Comment: The selector should be optimal, right? I think the loop is clear, but the selectors should in theory loop through things less.

Comment: This is more or less what I did but I followed the other guys solution first before I saw yours.  I think yours would work as well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ddschmitz See the note I added at the bottom; `re.compile('.mp3')` should actually be `re.compile('\.mp3$')` since `.` is a special character in regex. You also want the `$` anchor since you want to match the end of the string.